# WSO2 changes order of JSON nodes causing checksum error

Tags: xml, wso2

I have a service that accepts client request in below format

```
{ 
"payload": { 
    "addField1": "",
    "addField2": "",
    "addField3": "",
    "addField4": "",
    "addField5": "",
    "addField6": "",
    "addField7": "",
    "addField8": "",
    "addField9": "NA",
    "addField10": "NA"
},
"checksum":"e932c36d4a67715e9814125098601a3d4052148d0bbc4cbfacfe827ac23845a5a226ae3bcd90f2595800605c6c966d057419d6b12b242247190f329d1c926c0e"
}
```

Then i pickup the payload and checksum and send it to Checksum verification service using payload mediator

```
<payloadFactory description="IdMgmtPayload" media-type="json">
<format>
        {
        "req": {
        "payload":$1, 
        },
        "checkSum": "$2"
        }
    </format>
<args>
  <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('payload')"/> 
  <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('checksum')"/>
</args>
</payloadFactory>
```

But while forming the message using Payload factory, order of json nodes gets changed and check verification fails

Request generated by payload factory is

```
{
        "req": {
        "payload":{"addField6":"","addField5":"","addField8":"","addField7":"","addField2":"","addField1":"","addField4":"","addField3":"","addField10":"NA","addField9":"NA"} 
        },
        "checkSum": "3c81b7019854925a09c927069d1801496df3a9585e71a652a85db660adc00ebc938e5ed580c4c0b047e1f5a99d24083e78ac561a49aa1261c8ef4942f13270e7"
        }
```

How can I maintain the order of nodes?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any json library guarantees the node order because [json spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) says the order does not matter.

> An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value pairs,
> where a name is a string and a value is a string, number, boolean,
> null, object, or array.
>
> An array is an ordered sequence of zero or more values.

So to have the spec compliance, your checksum verification service should be fixed to ignore the node order when verifying.

Comment: Hi, My checksum is actually a hash of the json request. So changing even a single character will change the checksum

Comment: In that case, you shouldn't manipulate the request payload at all. Instead, you can try sending the request payload as it is and send the checksum via a http header.

Comment: If i use '<arg evaluator="xml" expression="//jsonObject/payload"/>' for payload factory arg, the order is maintained. But now  blank ("") values get replaced by null.